# How do I get R to go through a .csv file and make a plot for everyother column of data?

Tags: r, csv, plot, automation

I have this large spreadsheet that I have saved as a .csv file.  The spreadsheet has two "header" rows and is then arranged by columns as: file name, MZ, Area, MZ, Area...  What I need to do is call the file, I figured out how to do this with both of the headers, then have R create several barplots.  I need the bar plots to be for each of the "Area" columns, the ylim=lower and upper bounds of the data and have the title=the value in the MZ column right before the area.  I have created a script to make the barplot for the first column but it is not automated and does not correctly name the plot.  I have used both color and density to show the cyclical nature of the experimental set-up. 
Here is an abbreviated table.

```
structure(list(Data.File = c("20150420_04_01Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", 
"20150420_04_02Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", "20150420_04_03Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", 
"20150420_04_04Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", "20150420_04_05Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", 
"20150420_05_01Ecoli_treat_0.250.d"), MZ = c(540.3073, 540.3073, 
540.3073, 540.3073, 540.3073, 540.3073), Area = c(252984.6656, 
256032.4732, 249261.4615, 253533.2804, 250352.2293, 255704.8124
), MZ.1 = c(513.2872, 513.2872, 513.2872, 513.2872, 513.2872, 
513.2872), Area.1 = c(505815.005, 502831.1187, 501745.5544, 510544.8462, 
511942.0494, 504955.7114), MZ.2 = c(244.1325, 244.1325, 244.1325, 
244.1325, 244.1325, 244.1325), Area.2 = c(473471.315, 480002.1109, 
471329.1703, 477518.5349, 474360.5241, 476703.0057), MZ.3 = c(442.2254, 
442.2254, 442.2254, 442.2254, 442.2254, 442.2254), Area.3 = c(659916.9366, 
638415.4196, 636272.8178, 668030.9817, 651146.1962, 639103.8294
), MZ.4 = c(360.6892, 360.6892, 360.6892, 360.6892, 360.6892, 
360.6892), Area.4 = c(606414.6122, 595299.5358, 584649.0941, 
601272.5988, 585518.7376, 588818.7567), MZ.5 = c(226.0354, 226.0354, 
226.0354, 226.0354, 226.0354, 226.0354), Area.5 = c(38955.65059, 
39102.04637, 39282.88698, 40731.99391, 40280.5906, 38387.9069
), MZ.6 = c(170.0572, 170.0572, 170.0572, 170.0572, 170.0572, 
170.0572)), .Names = c("Data.File", "MZ", "Area", "MZ.1", "Area.1", 
"MZ.2", "Area.2", "MZ.3", "Area.3", "MZ.4", "Area.4", "MZ.5", 
"Area.5", "MZ.6"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any suggestions you may be able to offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is there a way to add a small .csv file to this format as an example?  I am new to the format and relatively new to "R" and coding in general.  I struggle but can generally read code given enough time.

Comment: You can pust the result of `dput(head(dat))`. If there are too many columns, you can select just the first few since there's a pattern

Comment: I hope the is enough: structure(list(Data.File = c("20150420_04_01Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", 
"20150420_04_02Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", "20150420_04_03Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", 
"20150420_04_04Ecoli_treat_0.00.d", "20150420_04_05Ecoli_treat_0.00.d"), MZ = c(540.3073, 540.3073, 
540.3073, 540.3073, 540.3073, 540.3073), Area = c(252984.6656, 
256032.4732, 249261.4615, 253533.2804, 250352.2293, 255704.8124
), MZ.1 = c(513.2872, 513.2872, 513.2872, 513.2872, 513.2872, 
513.2872), Area.1 = c(505815.005, 502831.1187, 501745.5544, 510544.8462, 
511942.0494), MZ.2 = c(244.1325, 244.1325, 244.1325, 
244.1325, 244.1325)

Comment: Your code got truncated, you should edit the question to add it.

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nn<-length(scan(file=paste0("file.csv"),what="",sep=",",nlines=1,skip=2))
dt<-fread("file.csv",header=T,skip=1L,select=seq(2,nn,by=2))
mzs<-unlist(fread("file.csv",header=T,skip=1L,
                  select=seq(1,nn,by=2),nrows=1L))
lapply(1:length(mzs),function(x)barplot(unlist(dt[,x,with=F]),main=mzs[x]))
```

1. Use `scan` to figure out programmatically how many columns there are. `skip=2` is intended to skip to the line of headers.
2. Only read the `Area` columns--if you're sure they're all the even-numbered columns. I'm skipping the `MZ` columns here because it would be inefficient to read in all of those repeated values.
3. Only read the `MZ` columns, and only read the first value (because we know it's simply repeated)
4. Plot; without reproducible data, I'm not sure if we have to set `ylim` or `xlim` manually.

Comment: When I try to use this I get the following error:  Error in unlist(fread("A:/Data/6520/RT experiments/20150420_Ecoli0250_05_20150707_Processed_Table.csv",  : could not find function "fread";   I replaced "file.csv" with my file name and location.  The error here seems to be a missing function.  Am I missing an R package?

Comment: yes, sorry, I should have made that more clear; edited.

Comment: Thank you for your help to this point.  I have been trying to correct an error that is originating from the "dt" line of code.  The error is "Error in is.finite(to) : default method not implemented for type 'closure'".  I assume this is an error due to non-number entries but when I remove them it does not solve the problem; in addition, for the working code I cannot just remove the sample names.  Any ideas?

Comment: are you replacing `ncol` with an actual number? I'm not sure but I suspect you're actually trying to pass the function `ncol` (see `?ncol`) instead of an integer number of columns, which is what I intended. See my edit.

Comment: I have the code reading the .csv file.  When I try to create the graphs I get an error:  "Error in barplot.default(dt[, x, with = F], main = mzs[x]) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix"  I am able to get some graphs out of the code if I add as.matrix after the barplot command but the plots are not usable.

Comment: I see. `dt[,x,with=F]` is returning a `data.table`; `barplot` doesn't know what to do with it. The edited code should work.

Comment: The code works great on a small sample data set but when I try and analyze the entire (very large .csv) file all I get is a rectangle block that is rainbow colored (I colored it).  I think this is a x/y limit issue.  Is there a way to set these limits based on the data in each individual column?  This is the code I used to generate the graphs:  lapply(1:length(mzs),function(x)barplot(unlist(dt[,x,with=F]),col=rainbow(9),main=mzs[x]));  Also can I display more than on plot per page?  something like: [3:3]  Vaguely remember this option...

Comment: I think we've reached the limit of being able to help with the issue you asked about. Try `barplot(1:10)`. If any of your `Area` vectors are long (say `length(Area)=n`), it's going to try to make a `barplot` with `n` columns--this will be illegible if `n` is large (cf. `barplot(1:1000)`). Basically, this is becoming more of a question of "how do I visualize my data better" and less about "how do I make barplots in this way".